# Multiple threads structure to process numerous inputs concurrently (in the VRP problem using or-tools)

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I wrote a Python code using the or-tools to handle the VRP problem, and it works perfectly. I set the 'self.parameters.time_limit.seconds'  to 180 seconds to have enough time to get the best results.
I have a module (written in C#) that generates an object from this code and executes it for each input that is supplied.
I also wrote a multi-threat code in C# to process several  inputs in parallel in order to be faster.
However, the outcomes are worse when I run every input together than when I run each one separately.

I kept track of the resource usage, and each CPU is using about 49 to 50 percent of its available resources. From what I can tell, RAM and CPU usage are both fine. I am unable to comprehend why this occurred, though. Does or-tools have conflict with multi threat structure?